# Pandas Pivot table and Excel's style cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, xlsxwriter

I get data measurements from instruments. These measurements depend on several parameters, and a pivot table is a good solution to represent the data. Every measurement can be associated to a scope screenshoot to be more explicit. I get all the data in the following csv format :

[image: Data sample]

The number of measurements and parameters can change.

I am trying to write a Python script (for now with Pandas lib) which allows me to create a pivot table in Excel. With Pandas, I can color the data in and out of a defined range. However, I would like also to to create a link on every cell who can send me to the corresponding screenshot. But I am stuck here.

I would like a result like the following (but with the link to the corresponding screenshot) :
[image: desired result]

Actually, I found out a way to add the link thanks to the **=HYPERLINK()** Excel function to all the cells with the **apply()** Pandas function.
However, I cannot apply a conditional formatting thanks to **xlsxWriter** anymore because the cells don't have a numerical content anymore

I can apply the conditional formatting first and then iterate through the whole sheet to add a link, but it will be a total mess to retrieve the relation between the data and the different parameters measurement

I would like your help to find ideas and efficient ways to do what I would like

Answer (score 0):

xlsxwriter has a function called  `write_url` ,but first while creating new worksheet you must apply  `write_url` and then use openyxl to insert your pandas data frame

1)create worksheet and insert  `write_url`

2)use openyxl to write data into already formatted cells.

Comment: write_url is what I would like to use. But, from xlsxwriter, how can I easily find the relation between the Pandas' values and the different Pandas' columns and index ?
In this way, I will need to parse the whole data by hand ?